# save Iframe's source as an image on desktop

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an Iframe in a webpage whose source is filled when a submit button is clicked.I need the iframe source to be saved as an image on my desktop .How can this be done.
Heres the code:

```
<iframe id="IFAEventPerformance" name="IFAEventPerformance" scrolling="auto" runat="server"
 width="100%" height="403" class=""></iframe>
```

and the cs file:

```
protected void lnkBTNSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
this.IFrame1.Attributes.Add("src", "https:\\anotherwebsitename");
}


function for export to ppt is:
 protected void imgBTNExportPPT_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {            
            //WebsiteToImage websiteToImage = new WebsiteToImage("http://www.google.co.in", @"C:\Users\312220\Desktop\myscreenshot.jpg");
            //websiteToImage.Generate();
            WebsiteToImage websiteToImage = new WebsiteToImage("C:\\Users\\304485\\Desktop\\Login.htm",(@"D:\\my\\chocos\\sample.jpg"));
            websiteToImage.Generate();
            TextBox txtTextBoxRetailGroup = (TextBox)uscRetailParameters.FindControl("txtRetailCustomerGroup");
            TextBox txtTextBoxPPGroup = (TextBox)uscRetailParameters.FindControl("txtProductGroup");
            TextBox txtTextBoxEventID = (TextBox)uscEventParameters.FindControl("txtEventId");

            string RetailGrp;
            RetailGrp = txtTextBoxRetailGroup.Text;
            string PPGrp;
            PPGrp = txtTextBoxPPGroup.Text;
            string EventID;
            EventID = txtTextBoxEventID.Text;

            ShowPresentation();
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an iframe available on your caller page. Load the ppt as the src/href for the frame.
If the users browser settings allow it, the ppt will be shown in the frame.

i believe this has nothing to do with .NET though

Comment: i have made certain changes to the requirements.Please look through.